# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true

Tags: flutter, bottom-navigation-bar

I am struggling to find a solution to this error --  'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.

I am attempting to add a bottomNavigationBar to my app, but whenever I attempt to enter the app homescreen, I recieve that error.  I don't get the error when I remove the bottomNavigationBar feature.

I tried looking it up and none of the available solutions seem to work.  Please help!

bottom_nav_button_bar.dart

```
import 'package:class_cred/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/profile.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/quests.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/settings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomNavButtonBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavButtonBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavButtonBar> createState() => _BottomNavButtonBarState();
}

class _BottomNavButtonBarState extends State<BottomNavButtonBar> {
  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: index,
        children: const [
          HomeScreen(),
          Quests(),
          Settings(),
          Profile(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int newIndex) {
          setState(() {
            index = newIndex;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: "Home",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            label: "Quests",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: "Home",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: "Home",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:class_cred/constants.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/password_screen.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/profile.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/quests.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/settings.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/start_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent_tab_view.dart';

import 'store.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ClassCred());
}

class ClassCred extends StatelessWidget {
  const ClassCred({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ClassCred',
      //debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 3,
              color: Color(0xff7ed6df),
            ),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: kOffWhite),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: const Scaffold(),
      initialRoute: '/start',
      routes: {
        '/start': (context) => const StartScreen(),
        '/password': (context) => const PasswordScreen('email'),
        '/home': (context) => const HomeScreen(),
        '/register': (context) => const RegisterScreen(),
        '/settings': (context) => const Settings(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:class_cred/bottom_nav_button.dart';
import 'package:class_cred/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavButtonBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: SizedBox(
                child:
                    Image.asset('assets/images/character_and_background.png'),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 30,
              top: 20,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/level_back.png',
                    height: 200,
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '12',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lalezar(
                          fontSize: 125,
                          //color: kGreenlandGreen,
                          letterSpacing: 2,
                          color: kDullYellowColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '12',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lalezar(
                          fontSize: 125,
                          //color: kGreenlandGreen,
                          letterSpacing: 2,
                          foreground: Paint()
                            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                            ..strokeWidth = 6
                            ..color = Colors.black54,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
              right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: kOffWhite,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      border: Border.all(width: 5, color: kGreenlandGreen),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  'assets/images/avatar_icon.png',
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text('John Doe', style: kSubheadingXLTextStyle),
                            Text(
                              'XP: 200',
                              style: kSubheadingLargeTextStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: kOffWhite,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      border: Border.all(width: 5, color: kGreenlandGreen),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am expecting to be able to add a navigation bar to the bottom of my app that will allow me to select different icons that sends me to different screens on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be glad to help you out, but it would be easier for others to assist you if your question was framed more clearly. When using Stack Overflow, it's important to include a minimal code sample to reproduce the error and provide the relevant portion of your stack trace. It seems like the source of your problem may be in the bottom_nav_button_bar.dart file, and the code appears to be a bit unconventional. You might consider using an AppBar for the bottom bar instead. Here's an example:

```
return AppBar(
      actions: [
        PopupMenuButton(
          icon: const Icon("Chosse you icon"),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return [
              
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: ListTile(

              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: ListTile(
                  
              )
            ];
          },
        ),
      ],
      title: "write something if you want"
}
```

By following these suggestions, you'll make it easier for others to understand your issue and provide the help you need.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, as I am new to programming and StackOverflow, I am unsure of the standards and best practices.  I will continue to learn and evolve my questioning to make it more legible for others.  Thank you again for your help and guidance.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? if not, i still can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the bottom navigation bar wrongly. The class/widget `BottomNavButtonBar` you created isn't a bottom navigation bar but a full view/screen with 4 tabs and a bottom navigation bar. Doing `bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavButtonBar()` in your homescreen is wrong and you should treat the `BottomNavButtonBar()` as a full view/screen/page on its own.

You may want to visit the docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) on how to use the bottom navigation bar,